# Accessing javax.smartcardio from windows?

Tags: java, error-handling, smartcard-reader, cardreader

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.smartcardio.*;
public class Terminals{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception{
        TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault ();
        System.out.println ("Default factory: "+factory);
        dumpTerminals (factory);
        factory = TerminalFactory.getInstance ("PC/SC", null);
        System.out.println ("PC/SC factory: "+factory);
        dumpTerminals (factory);
    }
    static void dumpTerminals (TerminalFactory factory) throws Exception{
        List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals ().list ();
        for (CardTerminal terminal: terminals)
            System.out.println (terminal);
    }
}
```

This code is not detecting COM port in WINDOWS 8.1 pro . It prints `Default factory: TerminalFactory for type None from provider None` and some errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: PC/SC, provider: SunPCSC, class: sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC$Factory)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1259)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:243)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:190)
    at javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory.getInstance(TerminalFactory.java:243)
    at Terminals.main(Terminals.java:10)
Caused by: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: SCARD_E_NO_SERVICE
    at sun.security.smartcardio.PCSC.SCardEstablishContext(Native Method)
    at sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCTerminals.initContext(PCSCTerminals.java:56)
    at sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC$Factory.<init>(SunPCSC.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1254)
    ... 4 more
```

even though MIFARE card reader is connected to laptop at COM port .
    I tried multiple times by disconnecting and connecting never succeed .I had installed required driver for card reader device driver is working properly.

```
Why it's not recognising card reader?
```

Comment: Does this apply? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2011/05/19/scardestablishcontext-fails-with-scard-e-no-service-error.aspx

Comment: Do you have a PC/SC driver installed for your reader? Does your reader even support PC/SC?

Comment: @MichaelRoland yes , i had installed PC/SC driver on com25 port .When i used python then it works .